# can git merge two files ignoring their common ancestor

Tags: git

For example I have the following file:

```
// first part
function() {
    var timer = 1;
}

// second part
function() {
    var timer = 2;
}

// third part
function() {
    var timer = 3;
}
```

Now two different branches change it. I have changes:
in branch1:

```
// first part
function() {
    var timer = "changed in branch1";
}

// second part
function() {
    var timer = 2;
}

// third part
function() {
    var timer = 3;
}
```

in branch2:

```
// first part
function() {
    var timer = 1;
}

// second part
function() {
    var timer = "changed in branch2";
}

// third part
function() {
    var timer = 3;
}
```

With 3-way merge these changes will merge clean because each branch changed a chunk of code different from the other one. However, when merged I want the following:

```
// first part
function() {
<<<<<<< branch1
    var timer = "changed in branch1";
=======
    var timer = 1;
>>>>>>> branch2
}

// second part
function() {
<<<<<<< branch1
    var timer = 2;
=======
    var timer = "changed in branch2";
>>>>>>> branch2
}

// third part
function() {
    var timer = 3;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this kind of merge in git? I assume based on the comments this kind of merge would be something like this:

1. make diff of a file
2. insert in the final version chunks not in a diff
3. mark chunks that differ with conflict markers

Comment: Just curious, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @mu無, well mostly out of curiosity as well :). Also, we have a team member, who sometimes changes my code of `featureA` in `master` while I'm working on the other feature and don't touch `featureA` code so when merged I get no conflict. And after some time in the future I discover that `featureA` is broken. So maybe I'd want to merge some files without common ancestor to see if code of `featureA` in master is different from the same code in my version in different branch.

Comment: If the reason is another dev's changes, I think they would be better handled by a proper code review process. That said, you can always check the diff as answers below suggest :)

Comment: @mu無, proper code reviews or firing this developer is indeed what should be done here, but I just told you what situation got me into thinking about such kind of merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git offers the plumbing command `git merge-file` that will allow you to do a merge of two files without a base, however there is not a simple way to invoke this.  If you are merging `branch` into `master` and want to do a baseless merge of some file `foo.txt`:

```
git show master:foo.txt > /tmp/master.foo.txt
git show branch:foo.txt > /tmp/branch.foo.txt
echo -n > /tmp/empty.txt
git merge-file -p -L master -L base -L branch /tmp/master.foo.txt /tmp/empty.txt /tmp/branch.foo.txt > foo.txt
```

In the above example, this produces:

```
// first part
function() {
<<<<<<< master
    var timer = 1;
=======
    var timer = "changed in branch1";
>>>>>>> branch
}

// second part
function() {
<<<<<<< master
    var timer = "changed in branch2";
=======
    var timer = 2;
>>>>>>> branch
}

// third part
function() {
    var timer = 3;
}
```

(Scripting this is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: thanks, will it merge the file in my question the way it is described there?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, exactly like you proposed.  Updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: I see, thanks, I'll try later and get back with questions if anything :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the differences between your code and a certain commit, just do:

```
git diff HEAD..<sha-commit2>
```

or if you want to compare current commit with the tip of another branch:

```
git diff HEAD..other_branch
```

**EDIT**
As @Maximus asked in the comment: if you want to see the changes made by someone

- on the master branch
- in particular files
- since the time you branched

So we need to find the common ancestor first: (I suppose you are on your branch; whence I am using HEAD. Can be replaced by your branch name)

```
git merge-base HEAD master
```

then you can see the changes since that common ancestor in particular files (`git log -p` or `git diff`; depends on the output you like):

```
git log -p <sha-common-ancestor>..master -- <the files and dirs you want>
git diff <sha-common-ancestor>..master -- <the files and dirs you want>
```

Comment: No, I actually do want to merge. I wan't git to do `git diff` job for me and merge equal code and put conflicts inside files. Please see my comment to the answer for the reason why.

Comment: I understand your problem; you want to check the work of another developer before merging; that's why I propose you to first check the differences before merging. An alternative is to check his branch (if he has any); and see what he's been doing...

Comment: Yeah, but that's code review process and I'm talking about merging here. So maybe to put it another way I want to be notified if something has changed in the code in particular files since the time I branched out instead of manually check it every time.

Comment: @Maximus I edited my answer; I hope this answers better what you ask for. This allows you easily to create a bash oneliner or a script (or even a git alias)

Comment: thanks for your edit, it still doesn't answer my question but might be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use `git merge`**`--no-commit`**, then fix it up after the fact, before committing the merge result.  That's the easiest method (by far) for one-offs.

If you need a repeatable method of doing it automatically, you can define a custom merge driver (see, e.g., [this nabble thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/How-to-install-and-use-a-custom-merge-driver-td2230038.html)).  However, you must then come up with some systematic rules for how to combine apparently-non-conflicting changes.

Comment: `-- no-commit` just skips creating commit after the merge, but the merge is still happening using `3-way merge` strategy so the example in my question will merge clean.

Comment: Exactly.  You then edit the file and `git add` the result, to override the merge that git produced, before doing the commit. ... Oh, I see, you don't care about the *result* at this point, you want the *conflict markers*.  There's nothing built in to do that, as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, `conflict markers` is a by-product of merge happening disregarding common ancestor, the merge that does something like this `make diff of a file, insert in the final version chunks not in a diff, mark chunks that differ with conflict markers.